# The For Loop explanation

Tags: java

```
class Prime {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, j;
        boolean isprime;

        for (i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
            isprime = true;

            //See if the number is evenly disible 
            for (j = 2; j <= i / j; j++) // if it is , then it's not prime.
            {
                if ((i % j) == 0) {
                    isprime = false;
                }
            }

            if (isprime) {
                System.out.println(i + " is prime.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alright, could someone please explain this code to me. I kinda understand it and ran it through the command prompt. But I still have some confusion with the for loop "`for ( j=2;  j <= i/j;  j = ++)`"...why do we have to divide i over j?

Running though the first sequence of the code:
did j increment? I suppose not cause the condition `j <= i/j---2<= 2/2` is not true. Correct me if I'm wrong...does i increment when the whole program is finished or before j?

Comment: until i reach 4 second for loop going to be false(not executing).and i/j  integer division always return integer value..then think about prime series 2,3 there and next is 5 check inside if it makes fails for 4.so everything fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to... but, if you do, you can make your code run faster.

Let's say you wrote it like this:

```
for ( i=2 ; i<100 ; ++i )
{
    isprime = true ;
    for ( j=2 ; j<100 ; ++j )
    {
        if ( (i%j) == 0 )
        {
            isprime = false ;
            break ;
        }
    }

    if ( isprime )
    {
        System.out.println ( i + " is prime." ) ;
    }
}
```

This code would absolutely work. It's basically saying

For every number, i, in the range [2,100)...
For every number, j, in the range [2,100)...
If i is divisible by j with no remainder, then i is not not prime.

However, you KNOW that i is never evenly divisible by things bigger than it, so you could optimize the loop to read:

```
for ( i=2 ; i<100 ; ++i )
{
    isprime = true ;
    for ( j=2 ; j<i ; ++j )
    {
        if ( (i%j) == 0 )
        {
            isprime = false ;
            break ;
        }
    }

    if ( isprime )
    {
        System.out.println ( i + " is prime." ) ;
    }
}
```

Which does the same thing, but only runs j up to (but not including) i. But you can speed this up even more because, if a number is divisible by one number greater than its square root, it's also evenly divisible my a second number smaller than its square root.

So you could compute the square root yourself... Or you could do this:

```
for ( i=2 ; i<100 ; ++i )
{
    isprime = true ;
    for ( j=2 ; j<=i/j ; ++j )
    {
        if ( (i%j) == 0 )
        {
            isprime = false ;
            break ;
        }
    }

    if ( isprime )
    {
        System.out.println ( i + " is prime." ) ;
    }
}
```

So, let's say i=5. The inner loop will go:

```
j=1, so i/j=5, so we test this
j=2, so i/j=2, so we test this
j=3, so i/j=1, so we don't test this - because obviously the number I have chosen is greater than the square root
```

At this point, you know that the number you've chosen is greater than the square root, so you can stop searching.

The advantage of this lets you also not have to call the sqrt() function, which is slow.

Comment: Thanks very much this sure helped:) You seem pretty thorough on this hope one day I become as good as you:)